# Can scp from shell, cannot scp from apache

Tags: php, apache, shell, lamp

I have a LAMP database with a php script that copies an image from a server to the local server.  When I run the script via browser, it creates the directory, but does not copy images into the folder.  When the script runs it posts (echos) the command to the browser For example:

```
scp -i /home/jim/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.0.120:/images/55036249
/056-0039.* "/home/jim/images/_Retrieve/CARL EVANSON/2010-03-20 
55036249-056-0039.jpg"
```

When I run the above from a shell, it works, it copies the image.

This is the script:

```
$foo = sprintf("mkdir \"/home/jim/images/_Retrieve/%s\"",$name);
system($foo);
$foo = sprintf("scp -i /home/jim/.ssh/id_rsa root@192.168.0.120:/images
/%s/%03d-%04d.* \"/home/jim/images/_Retrieve/%s/%s
%s-%03d-%04d.jpg\"",$jid,$card,$image,$name,$date,$jid,$card,$image);
```

The script appears to be outputting the correct command, because it works when I run it in a shell.  When I run it in a browser it makes the folder but does not copy the images.  When I look at the httpd/error_log it says "Host Key Verification Failed."

Why doesn't it work when I run it via the browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the permission on the folder and images to see if they are accessible from Apache? The active user is not the same as your login.

Comment: On the command line, it runs SCP as you (run whoami to see who you are in case you aren't sure). In the web browser, it runs as apache. Does apache have the .ssh keys to do a login to the remote server? I doubt it would.

Comment: kainaw's on the right track. ssh key files have very strict permissions, so your web server user will not have read access to your keys.

Comment: Yes, kainaw and glenn jackman were on the right track.  It turned out to be conflicting entries in the root/.ssh/known_hosts file.  Apparently an iteration of the server (they are virtual machines) had already been keyed, which is why the httpd/error log was reporting "Host Key Verification Failed".